# LAMP Installation on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - issue with phpmyadmin installation

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp, phpmyadmin

I get below error when installing phpmyadmin

Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.8) but 7.4.28-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Can any one advise?

Comment: Are you using a different repository for your PHP packages, such as `ondrej`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to purge [problematic](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+ppa-packages) [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php
```

and then resume PHPMyAdmin installation by `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` .